# How to update quanity of cart in PHP with session?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, cart

I have an array of `shopping_cart` in my session, a `shopping_cart` is an array of id, title, price, image, and quantity, when i press the update button after changing the quantity of product, it change all products quantity which are in cart. i want to change only one product quantity based on item id.
here is my PHP code

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["update"]) && isset($_GET["id"])) {
  $uid = $_GET["id"];
  $u_qty = $_POST["u_qty"];

foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => &$values) {
  if ($values['item_id'] == $uid) {
    $values["item_quantity"] = $_POST["u_qty"];
  }

  }

}
```

here is HTML code

```
<tbody>
      <?php
      if (!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {
      ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <figure class="media">
                <div class="img-wrap"><img src="<?php echo $values["item_img"]; ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-sm"></div>
                <figcaption class="media-body">
                  <h6 class="title text-truncate"><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?> </h6>
                </figcaption>
              </figure>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span>$ <?php echo $values["item_price"]; ?></span>
            </td>
            <td>
            <form method="post" action="cart.php?action=update&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>">
                                                                      
                <input type="number" name="u_qty" style="width: 70px;" id="" min="1" value="<?php 
                 echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?>">
            </td>
            <td>
              <span>
                $ <?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"], 2); ?>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td class=" text-right">
              <a href="session.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>" class="btn 
                 btn-outline-danger"> × Remove</a>
              <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            </td>
          </tr>
          </form>
          <?php $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);  ?>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="total text-right">
          <h4>Total Amount: $<?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></h4>
        </div>
      <?php

      } else {
        echo "Empty cart";
      }

      ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: php code looks OK. I guess that code is in the cart.php file. What is the problem? I guess the item quantities are not updated? Although they should.

Comment: @Andreas item quantities are updating but all the items which are in cart but i want to update only one item which i am updating. and both html and php code is in cart.php file.